# Cloned node entity reference field stay in sync with parent node

Tags: entities

I have three content types A, B and C. A have entity reference fields to B and C. I create a Node of type A say a1. When i clone a1 node as a2 with node clone module i get the same value for entity reference fields in a2 same as a1. In a2 i can change the entity reference field value so that they refer to another nodes of B and C content type.

But with node clone module there is no way to maintain relationship between parent node and cloned node.

So I basically have two requirements:

1. In cloned node i can override the entity reference field value or leave it same as parent node. If i override, later i should be able to revert back to those values same as parent node. Currently there is no way to do this.
2. If parent node change the value of those entity reference fields then in all the cloned node of this parent node also change their respective entity reference field value except overridden cloned nodes.

The solution i found so far during searching is using [Replicate](https://drupal.org/project/replicate), [replicate_ui](https://drupal.org/project/replicate_ui) module which provide more hook to alter the cloning process. The another module is [Corresponding Entity References](https://drupal.org/project/cer) which create entity reference field back to parent node.

I don't need comprehensive solution but anything existing solution can do almost this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

1) You could use a hidden field of the same type with the same information. This way, the information relating the parent to child can be reverted, regardless of the changes or overrides. Use Rules to populate the duplicate field. Create a "Revert" button on the node and again use Rules, or as a form submit to react to copy the information from the hidden field to the visible one.

2) Use Rules to adjust any child nodes when the parent is saved/updated. This would act on both the hidden and visible field, with a condition on the visible (not to change if it has been overridden).

You could also write a module to do this, but I think it can be done with just Rules.